# The problem with Tuesday (foreign language string indexing)

Tags: unicode, julia

Here is a probably misspelled word for Tuesday in what may be a Turkish dialect:
  `"Çkinci gÜn"`. The spelling does not matter for the problem. My problem is this one:

```
s =  "Çkinci"
srev = reverse(s)
for i in 1:length(srev)
    println(srev[i])
end
```

works, but

```
for i in 1:length(s)
    println(s[i])
end
```

errors on the second letter. In fact, Çkinci, but not its reversed string, cannot be indexed at the letter k at position 2.

Does anyone know why? Is "Çk" a Unicode escape sequence or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Julia uses UTF-8 encoding of strings. Actually character `'Ç'` takes 2 bytes. So you should rather write:

```
julia> for v in s
           println(v)
       end
Ç
k
i
n
c
i
```

You can read the details about string indexing here: https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/strings/#Unicode-and-UTF-8-1.

The reason why the `reverse` version worked is that characters `k`,`i`,`n`,`c`,`i` are all ASCII and take only 1 byte so you did not hit a multi-byte character before you have finished and by accident `length` (which returns number of *characters* in the string) is equal to 6 which is the position of `Ç` in `reverse(s)`. However, actually your string takes 7 bytes as you can check by calling:

```
julia> ncodeunits(s)
7

julia> sizeof(s)
7

julia> length(s)
6
```

**EDIT:**
In Julia strings use byte indexing not character indexing when calling `getindex` on them. This is for performance reasons as in UTF-8 the cost of fining n-th character index is O(n).

If you want to get a byte index of `i`-th character in your string `s` write `nextind(s, 0, i)`. E.g. `s[nextind(s, 0, i)]` will return you `i`-th character in the string `s`. Note that you should use it only if you want to get one character from the string. If you need many it is more efficient to use iteration over the string.

Comment: The problem does require indexing, so I am going to have to do a split("Çkinci", "") to make it indexable I think.

Comment: If your problem requires indexing use `nextind` or `prevind` functions to get consecutive valid indices in your string.

Comment: And if you need character index, not a byte index (which is returned by `nextind`/`prevind`) simply write `for (i, c) in enumerate(s)` to get an index and a character.